# CakePHP 2.x Exception Handling in JSON

Tags: cakephp, exception

I'm working on a REST app with CakePHP and I'm trying to utilize built-in Exception handling in CakePHP 2.x.
For instance using

```
throw new UnauthorizedException('User not logged in');
```

will result in producing 401 page with content type as text/html. but what I want to achieve is the error page as JSON for content type.
I tried

```
$this -> response -> type('json');
```

in the controller but apparently CakePHP will bypass this when throwing exceptions ...

Answer (score 2):

Use the request handler component, and send proper JSON requests, that is, either appending a `.json` extension to the URL (requires extension parsing to be enabled), or sending a
`Accept: application/json` header.

CakePHPs built-in exception renderer will then automatically use serialized data views, and respond with JSON like

```
{
    "name": "User not logged in",
    "message": "User not logged in",
    "url": "\/the\/url.json"
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > JSON and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Components > Request Handling](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Connecting Routes > File Extensions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions)**

Answer (score -1):

I managed to handle this by modifying CakePHP Exception Renderer module:

```
/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php
```

added this:

```
$this->controller->response->type('json');
```

to function **render**.

Now all of my exceptions are rendered as JSON.

Comment: That's probably one of the worst possible solutions, you should never modify the core code, not only are your changes going to be lost with every update, but you cannot even be sure whether they will still be appliable afterwards. Do it the Cake way instead!